# Auto margin not working

Tags: css, centering

The text in my li's don't seem to be centering I am using margin: 10px auto; and it isn't working, also I tried using the margin: 0 auto to center the whole ul but that isn't working either
here is the css

```
ul.mainpackages {margin: 0 auto; height: 40px; width: 100%; }
ul.mainpackages li {
    border-top-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-top-style: double;
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-top-color: #FDFECD;
    border-bottom-color: #FDFECD;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 60px;
}
ul.mainpackages li p{
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

and the html

```
<ul class="mainpackages">
<li class="first1"><p>Pick a package that suits you!</p></li>
<li class="last1"><p>Special deals &amp; offers!</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `text-align` property to center text? (and change margin to `margin-top: 10px`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your paragraph is 100% wide, so when you try to center it...

You should either set the width or text-align: center inside the paragraph

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify a width on the `<p>` before using `margin: 0 auto;`

```
ul.mainpackages li p{
margin: 10px auto;
font-size: 16px;
width: 180px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bWN9V/)